# How do I display the next element of a list in a for loop inside the template

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

views.py

```
def cust_ledger(request, pk):
    cust = Customer.objects.get(id = pk)
dbs = [Issue, Receive, SalesReturn]

transactions = sorted(
    [m
    for db in dbs
    for m in db.objects.filter(customer=cust).order_by('date_time')], 
    key=attrgetter('date_time')
)

    quant_bal = 0

    amt_bal = 0

    sb_q = 0
    rb_q = 0
    sr_q = 0

    main = []

    for tx in transactions:
        if tx.tt == 'SB':
            # Individual tx
            sb_q = sb_q + tx.quantity
            main.append(sb_q)


            # Total
            quant_bal = quant_bal + tx.quantity
            amt_bal = amt_bal + tx.amount
        
        elif tx.tt == 'RB':
            rb_q = sb_q - tx.quantity
            main.append(rb_q)

            # Total
            quant_bal = quant_bal - tx.quantity
            amt_bal = amt_bal - tx.amount

        
        else:
            sr_q = sb_q - tx.quantity
            main.append(sr_q)

            # Total
            quant_bal = quant_bal - tx.quantity
            amt_bal = amt_bal - tx.amount


    

    context = {'transactions':transactions, 'cust':cust, 'quant_bal':quant_bal, 'amt_bal':amt_bal,
                'sb_q':sb_q, 'rb_q':rb_q, 'sr_q':sr_q,
                'main':main}

    
    return render(request, 'customer/ledger.html', context)
```

HTML template

```
    {% extends 'base2.html' %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% load static%}

{% block css %} 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'utility.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'customer/ledger.css' %}">

{% endblock css %}


{% block unique %}


    <div class="header">
        <a class="link inv" href="{% url 'inventory' %}"> Inventory</a>
        <a class="link hist" href="{% url 'cust_board' %}"> Dashboard</a>
        <h1>Dinar Company</h1>
        <a class="link home" href="{% url 'cust-l' %}">Back</a>
    </div>

{% endblock unique %}

{% block content %}    
    
    <div class="title_div">
        <h1 class="title">{{cust.name}}'s Ledger</h1>
    </div>

    <h2 class="date heading">Date</h2>

    <h2 class="tt heading">TT</h2>

    <h2 class="id heading">ID</h2>

    <h2 class="voucher heading">Voucher</h2>

    <h2 class="debit_q heading">Debit Quantity(g)</h2>
    <h2 class="debit_c heading">Debit Cash</h2>

    <h2 class="credit_q heading">Credit Quantity(g)</h2>
    <h2 class="credit_c heading">Credit Cash</h2>

    <h2 class="balance_q heading">Balance Quantity(g)</h2>

    <h2 class="balance_c heading">Balance Cash</h2>
    
    <div class="flex-wrap">
        {% for tx in transactions %}

            {% if tx.tt == 'SB' %}
                <a href="{% url 'issue-detail' tx.id %}">

            {% elif tx.tt == 'RB' %}
                <a href="{% url 'rec-detail' tx.id %}">
                
            {% else %}
                <a href="{% url 'sr-detail' tx.id %}">
            {% endif %}
        
                    <div class="bar name">
                        <p class="p1">{{tx.date_time| date:"F j, Y"}}</p>
                        <p class="p2">{{tx.tt}}</p>
                        <p class="p3">{{tx.id}}</p>
                        <p class="p4">{{tx.voucher}}</p>

                        {% if tx.tt == 'SB' %}
                            <p class="p5 ic_q">{{tx.quantity}}g</p>
                            <p class="p6 ic_c">{{tx.amount}} SAR</p>
                            <p class="p5 rc_q">-</p>
                            <p class="p6 rc_c">-</p>

                        {% elif tx.tt == 'RB' %} 
                            <p class="p5 ic_q">-</p>
                            <p class="p6 ic_c">-</p>
                            <p class="p5 rc_q">{{tx.quantity}}g</p>
                            <p class="p6 rc_c">{{tx.amount}} SAR</p>
                            
                        {% else %}
                            <p class="p5 ic_q">-</p>
                            <p class="p6 ic_c">-</p>
                            <p class="p5 rc_q">{{tx.quantity}}g</p>
                            <p class="p6 rc_c">{{tx.amount}} SAR</p>

                        {% endif %}

                        {% for i in main %}

                            {% if tx.tt == 'SB' %}
                            <p class="p7">{{i}}g</p>
                            <p class="p8">{{sb_cash_bal}} SAR</p>                                                                                
                            
                            {% elif tx.tt == 'RB' %}
                                
                                <p class="p7">{{i}}g</p>
                                <p class="p8">{{rb_cash_bal}} SAR</p>                                                                   
                            
                            {% else %}
                                <p class="p7">{{i}}g</p>
                                <p class="p8">{{rb_cash_bal}} SAR</p>
                                

                            {% endif %}     

                        {% endfor %}                               
                    
                    </div>
                </a>                   
        {% endfor %}
        <div class="bar final">
            <h3>Total</h3>
            <p class="p9">{{quant_bal}}g</p>
            <p class="p10">{{amt_bal}} SAR</p>
        </div>    
    </div>
    

{% endblock content %}
```

I am passing a list `main` from my view to the template, what I want is to display first element of the list if any of the respective condition is met, then again iterate over the `main` list and do the same for the next element and so on. But when I am running the template it keeps repeating the first element of list wherever the condition is met.

Example:

```
main = [1,2,3]
```

lets say the first condition is true for all elements in main list. Now, the last for loop in template should return 1,2,3 but it is giving out 1,1,1

I have tried almost 5-6 methods to achieve that but none of them worked

Comment: You have not passed tx as context

Comment: I passed transactions as context and then ran a for loop on it in the template

Comment: `for tx in transactions:` from your `cust_ledger` view function should throw an error `NameError: name 'transactions' is not defined`? It's not clear from your example where `transactions` comes from. Sure, you pass it into the context, but that's after the for loop where you used the transactions variable, which is undefined at that point.

Comment: oh actually I removed the part from the question where transactions are defined, it seemed irrelevant to the question, anyway i'll add it back